# Quotients of curves of genus $4$ by a free $\mathbb{Z}/ 3 \mathbb{Z}$-action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $V_2$ and $V_3$ be the two hypersurfaces of $\mathbb P^3$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
V_2:={x_2x_3 + r(x_0, \, x_1)=0}, \quad V_3:={x_2^3+x_3^3+s(x_0, \, x_1)=0},
\end{equation*}
where $r, \, s \in \mathbb{C}[x_0, \, x_1]$ are general homogeneous forms of degree $2$ and $3$, respectively.

Then $C_4:=V_2 \cap V_3$ is a smooth, canonical curve of genus $4$.  Denoting by $\xi$ a primitive third root of unity, then $C_4$  admits a free action of the cyclic group $\langle \xi \rangle \cong \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$, defined by
\begin{equation*}
\xi \cdot [x_0: x_1:x_2:x_3] = [x_0: x_1: \xi x_2: \xi^2 x_3]
\end{equation*}
and the quotient $C_2 := C_4/ \langle \xi \rangle$ is a smooth curve of genus $2$.

A naive count of parameters shows that the number of moduli on which this construction depends is $$\dim |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)| + \dim |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(3)| - \dim G= 7 - \dim G,$$
where $G \subset \textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^4)$ is the subgroup of projectivities sending both $V_2$ and $V_3$ to hypersurfaces of the same form. If my computations are correct, $G$ has dimension $4$ so the construction actually depends on $3$ parameters.

On the other hand, $3$ is also the dimension of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_2$. This shows that the *general* curve $C_2$ of genus $2$ can be constructed in this way.

> **Question.**  Is it possible to obtain *all* smooth curves of genus $2$ by means of  this construction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Start from a genus 2 curve $C_2$, and choose a point of order 3 in $JC_2$, giving rise to  an étale $\mathbb{Z}/3$-covering $C_4\rightarrow C_2$. 
Then $C_4$ cannot be hyperelliptic: a $g^1_2$ on $C_4$ would be stable under the covering automorphism  $\sigma $, hence descend to $C_2$, which is impossible for degree reasons.   $\sigma $ acts on $H^0(C_4,K_{C_4})$ with eigenvalues $(1,1,\xi ,\xi ^2)$: the invariant part comes from $C_2$, and the trace must be 1 by the holomorphic Lefschetz formula. Writing down the  invariant quadric and cubic(s) containing $C_4$ leads to your formulas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is really helpful. I have a couple of questions.

**(1)** Your computations show that the curve $C_4$ embeds in $\mathbb P^4$ and must be invariant by the action $$[x_0: x_1 : x_2 : x_3] \mapsto [x_0: x_1 : \xi x_2 : \xi^2 x_3].$$
On the other hand, it is a canonical curve, so it is intersection of a (unique) quadric and a cubic. But why both the quadric and the cubic must be invariant, too?

Comment: **(2)** How can I detect the space of invariant cubics through the canonical curve? Using Koszul resolution I can compute $$h^0(\mathscr{I}_{C_4})=5,$$
and it seems to me that there are $8$ invariant monomials, namely
$$x_0^3, \, x_0^2x_1, \, x_0x_1^2, \, x_1^3, \, x_0x_2x_3, \, x_1x_2x_3, x_2^3, \, x_3^3.$$
Why you say  *Writing down the invariant quadric and cubic(s) containing $C_4$ leads to your formulas*? How can I check that there exist an invariant cubic containing $C_4$ and whose equation does not contain the invariant monomials $x_0x_2x_3, \, x_1x_2x_3$?

Comment: The invariance of both the quadric and the cubic did not follow from the uniqueness ?

Comment: The quadric is in the kernel of $\mathsf{S}^2H^0(C_4,K)\rightarrow H^0(C_4,2K)$. 
The invariant subspace in $\mathsf{S}^2$ has dimension 4; in $H^0(C_4,2K)$, it is $H^0(C_2,2K)$, which has dimension 3. Similarly, the kernel of 
$\mathsf{S}^3H^0(C_4,K)\rightarrow H^0(C_4,3K)$ has dimension 5, with eigenvalues $(1,1,1,\xi ,\xi ^2)$. The eigenvalues $(1,1,\xi ,\xi ^2)$ correspond to the multiples of the quadric, it remains one invariant cubic.

Comment: @Holonomia: the quadric through $C_4$ is unique (so necessarily invariant), but the cubic is not: there is a $5$-dimensional vector space of them.

Comment: Letting $Q$ be the invariant quadric, and $C$ the space of cubics, we have a short exact sequence $0 \to H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}(1)) Q \to C \to \mathbb{C} \to 0$ of $\mathbb{Z}/3$ representations, where $\mathbb{Z}/3$ acts trivially on the final $\mathbb{C}$. Such a sequence must split, the image of the splitting $\mathbb{C} \to C$ is an invariant cubic. (More explicitly, take any cubic $f$ not in $H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}(1)) Q$, then $(1/3) (f+\sigma f + \sigma^2 f)$ is an invariant cubic.)

Comment: Of course, this invariant cubic is not unique; I am just saying there is one, well defined modulo the invariants in $H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}(1)) Q$

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: OK, I understand. But since $Z_3$ is finite, abelian and acts linearly you have a simultaneous diagonalization hence fixed cubics, isn't it?.

Comment: @Holonomia: well, I see that the existence of an invariant cubic in the ideal of $C_4$ easily follows using David Speyer's averaging argument.

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: That's right I agree.

Comment: @abx: I checked the computations and everything seems ok, thank you again for your help. Just to be pedantic: if $Q$ is the invariant quadric, one obtains an invariant cubic of the form $V_3$ by taking a general element in the invariant subspace of $\mathsf{S}^3 H^0(C_4, \, K)$ and adding suitable multiples of $x_0Q$ and $x_1Q$ in order to get rid of the monomials $x_0x_1x_3$, $x_0x_2x_3$.